# Why can a function in $L^1(\partial \mathbb{D})$ be represented by a Fourier series?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces

I am looking for a reference to the claim that for any $f\in L^1(\partial \mathbb{D})$, where $\partial \mathbb{D}$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, $f(e^{i\theta})=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{in\theta}$ for almost all $\theta$.  I am inexperienced with both the Poisson kernel and Fourier transform, so I was hoping for a gentle explanation if these notions are required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. In fact, Kolmogorov constructed (1923) an example of a $L^1$ function whose Fourier series diverges almost everywhere (later improved to everywhere divergent).

Om the other hand, if $f\in L^p$ for some $p>1$, it's a deep theorem by Carleson (the $p=2$ case) and Hunt ($p>1$) that the Fourier series of $f$ converges pointwise almost everywhere. See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I was tripped up by misunderstanding the following statement I read in a book by Garnett: "Let $f(\theta)\in L^1$ have Fourier series $\displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{in\theta}$." What then does this Fourier series represent?

Comment: You can view a series as its sequence of partial sums if you like. It doesn't need to represent anything.

Comment: @user122916 Since $f \in L^1$, $a_n$ is well-defined (without having to worry about distribution theory). But the corresponding series isn't necessarily convergent.